# Visual Studio doesn't notice if I change Project Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I change either Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies, or VC++ Directories, the compiler behaves as though the changes did not happen.

That is, I can take all the additional dependencies out (though they are absolutely needed), and the project will still compile and link; or, if I don't initially put in the correct VC++ directories, adding those directories does not enable VS to find the files it needs.  (If I right-click a #include , with its red squiggly lines showing there's a problem, it will say, SDL.h not found in... and list a slew of directories, none of which are the one I added.)  This matters as I'm trying to determine which library is causing a conflict.

The IDE *shows* the changes I make when I reload Project Properties; it just won't act on them.  It does notice if I change the Windows SDK Version.

This is only happening on one of my computers.  I had recently installed Visual Studio 2019 Preview on it.  Although I was running 2017, I still tried uninstalling 2019 Preview; no effect.

By request, here's a sample error message of not finding the include file:

> c:\myProject\source\audiopath.cpp(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'audiopath.h': No such file or directory

And here's what I get if I try to load the include file by right-clicking #include:

> File 'audiopath.h' not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths.
>
> Current source file path: 'C:\myProject\source'
>
> Build system path:  [long list of directories, none of which are C:\myProject\include]

Here's what I have for Project Properties, VC++ Directories, Include Directories:

> $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);c:\myProject\include

and Project Properties, C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories is `c:\myProject\include`.

`c:\myProject\include` does indeed contain audiopath.h.

Comment: Confusing question without an explicit build error message.  You need to get rid of the red squiggles on the #include before you can anything else.  Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > "Additional include directories" setting.

Comment: OK, got explicit error message from build and otherwise.

Comment: I have also added c:\myProject\include to Project Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories; hadn't noticed that.  It hasn't repaired the error, though.

Comment: Make sure you are editing the right configuration (debug  /release/x86/x64) and that is marked as the current one in project properties.

Comment: Yes, aybassiouny, it was a problem with configurations.  Editing all of them together fixed it.  Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.  Tx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical case of editing properties of one configuration type (e.g. Release), and building another (e.g. Debug). In Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, when editing the project properties, always make sure that the selected configuration (Release/Debug) matches that of the one currently being edited. 
I found this to be happening a lot at my workplace.

Comment: I was going to award the answer to the first commenter who gave it, but it's been 6 days, so I'm accepting your answer (thanks!) instead.